# Selenium Webdriver Python I am trying to wait until data has completed processing in a html table. How do i know when the table is blank

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a webpage with a HTML table of 1 row and some columns.
The user selects the checkbox and then clicks the run button.
A process starts to run, data starts to be processed.
The HTML table, the column called "Progress" will show a progress bar with a percentage of how much has been completed.  It will show 100% when completed.
All the data shown in the columns, e.g. Name, company, Progress will go blank.
This means the process has completed.

Is there a way I can wait for the table to be empty, no data is being shown and then I know the processing has compelted.  I can then move onto the next test?

I have first tried to wait for all of the rows and columns of the table to be loaded and then print out the Name and Company columns using WebDriverWait.

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'operations_monitoring_tab_current_ct_fields_body')))
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Webdriver\ClearCore\TestCases\OperationsPage_TestCase.py", line 101, in test_add_and_run_clean_process
    process_lists_page.has_process_run_completed()
  File "C:\Webdriver\ClearCore\Pages\operations.py", line 239, in has_process_run_completed
    print col_name.text
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_table)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u25ba' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

My method so far is (operations.py):

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

def has_process_run_completed(self):
    try:
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'operations_monitoring_tab_current_ct_fields_body')))
        table_id = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'operations_monitoring_tab_current_ct_fields_body')))
        rows = table_id.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")
        for row in rows:
            # Get the columns
            col_name = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[1]  # This is the Name column
            col_company = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[2]  # This is the Company column
            #col_progress = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[3]  # This is the progress column
            #col_status = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[4]  # This is the Status column
            print col_name.text
            print col_company.text
            #print col_progress.text
            #print col_status.text
            return True
    except NoSuchElementException, e:
            return False
```

From my TestCase class OpeationsPage_TestCase.py to call the method is:

```
from Menus.project_navigator import ProjectNavigatorPage    
class OperationsPage_TestCase(BaseTestCase):

process_lists_page = project_navigator.select_projectNavigator_item("Process Lists") 
process_lists_page.click_checkbox_for_the_process("LADemo")
process_lists_page.click_run_and_monitor_button()
process_lists_page.has_process_run_completed()
```

The HTML of the table is:

```
<table id="operations_monitoring_tab_current_ct_fields_body" cellspacing="0" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;">
    <colgroup>
        <col style="width: 30px;" />
        <col style="width: 78px;" />
        <col style="width: 42px;" />
        <col style="width: 205px;" />
        <col style="width: 55px;" />
        <col style="width: 202px;" />
        <col style="width: 40px;" />
    </colgroup>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="GPI5XK1CFG GPI5XK1CMG" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="0">
            <td class="GPI5XK1CEG GPI5XK1CGG GPI5XK1CNG" __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-282" style="outline-style:none;">
                <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1" />
            </td>
            <td class="GPI5XK1CEG GPI5XK1CGG GPI5XK1CNG" __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-283" style="outline-style:none;">
                <span>
<span class="" title="" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;cursor:pointer;">►</span>
                </span>
                <span>
<span class="" title="LADemo" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;cursor:pointer;padding-left:3px;">LADemo</span>
                </span>
            </td>
            <td class="GPI5XK1CEG GPI5XK1CGG GPI5XK1CNG" __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-284" style="outline-style:none;">
                <span class="" title="" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;padding-right: 1px;" />
            </td>
            <td class="GPI5XK1CEG GPI5XK1CGG GPI5XK1CNG" __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-285" style="outline-style:none;">
                <div class="" title="" style="border-left:2px solid #9EC400;border-right:2px solid #9EC400;border-radius:5px;margin-right:2px;">
                    <div class="" title="9%" style="border-left:2px solid #9EC400;border-right:2px solid #9EC400;border-radius:5px;box-shadow:0 8px 6px -6px #bbb;text-shadow:0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);text-align: center;background-color: #9EC400;width:9%;">9%</div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="GPI5XK1CEG GPI5XK1CGG GPI5XK1CNG" __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-286" style="outline-style:none;">
                <div class="" title="Running" style="text-align:center;padding-top:3px;">
                    <img border="0" style="width:16px;height:16px;background:url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAKUAAJzGBNzuhPT6zNT2PPz+jPz+5OT6hLziHQQA7) no-repeat 0px 0px;" src="http://mypc.companyname.local:8080/clearcore/ClearCore/clear.cache.gif" onload="this.__gwtLastUnhandledEvent=" load ";"/>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="GPI5XK1CEG GPI5XK1CGG GPI5XK1CNG" __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-287" style="outline-style:none;">
                <span class="" title="LADEMO_IE_10_16_1521_18_58" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;padding-right: 1px;">LADEMO_IE_10_16_1521_18_58</span>
            </td>
            <td class="GPI5XK1CEG GPI5XK1CGG GPI5XK1CNG" __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-288" style="outline-style:none;">
                <span class="" title="" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;padding-right: 1px;" />
            </td>
            <td class="GPI5XK1CEG GPI5XK1CGG GPI5XK1CNG" __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-289" style="outline-style:none;">
                <span class="" title="" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;padding-right: 1px;" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I would like to poll the table and check is there any data shown in the columns.  It could even be just 1 of the columns.  When it is empty return true.  This way I know that the table is empty and the data processing has completed.
Is there a way to do it using a While loop perhaps?

Some help appreciated.  Thank you.
Riaz

Comment: `col_name_unicode = unicode(col_name.text) if not isinstance(col_name.text,unicode) else col_name.text` and now  `print col_name_unicode`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  It gets to the else part and shows the error UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u25ba' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: what do u mean by else part??

Comment: In the if statement there is an else.  The code i have put is  col_name_unicode = unicode(col_name.text)
                if not isinstance(col_name.text,unicode):
                    pass
                else:
                    print col_name_unicode

Comment: Oh sorry then try `unicode(col_name.text) if not isinstance(col_name.text,unicode) else col_name.text` and now `print col_name`

Comment: I get the same error.

Comment: `txt=col_name.text.encode('utf-8')`  `print txt`

Comment: This bit seems to have worked.  It has printed out the text â–ºLADemo some strange chars before the letter L

Comment: I think your sys.stdout.encoding or console encoding is not correct. Try to write in  a file.